# Im new at the discord bot scene and everytime i type in the terminal "node index.js" it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I installed nod.js;discord.js and Im using Windows 10. I had already managed to get the bot online onto the Discord server before the extra commands. If someone knows about it, you can write an answer.
(I deleted the owner ID and the Token)
The Code is:

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`)
const Client = new Discord.Client();
const OwnerID = ""

const prefix = "!"



Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ich bin jetzt online!");
    client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `VAPE eSports Bot` ,type: 0} }); 
})

// welcome message

Client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    member.guild.defaultChannel.sbed("Wilkommen zu: " + member.guild.name + "Wir hoffe es gefällt euch hier")

})

Client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log("Jemand hat den VAPE eSports Bot zu dem Server hinzugefügt, erstellt von " + guild.owner.user.username)
})

Client.on ("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
    command = command.slice(prefix.length);

    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

    if (command === "ping") {
        message.channel.send(`Pong! Time took : ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp} ms`);

 } else

if (command === "say" ) {
    message.delete()
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0x95D23)
    .setDescription(message.author.username + " sagte: " + args.join(" "))
    message.channel.send({embed})
 } else

if (command == "help") {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0x954D23)
    .setTitel("Befehl Liste:")
    .addField("!help", "Wird dir alle Befehle zeigen")
    .addField("!say [Text]", "Lässt den Bot etwas sagen")
    message.channel.send({embed})
 }

})

client.login("");
```

The error message is:

```
PS C:\Users\49174\Documents\Discord bot> node index.js
C:\Users\49174\Documents\Discord bot\index.js:58
client.login("NzIyNTM4NTk2NzM2Njk2MzIw.XuzLYw.DOYUQLRU-Q9zwutex5w9-lbo3N4");
^

ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\49174\Documents\Discord bot\index.js:58:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider removing that private key and using a placeholder - you should not leak those

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language, **casing** is very, very important.

`Client` and `client` are not the same thing.

```js
const Client = new Discord.Client();
```

Here you've defined `Client`, but you've never defined `client`. You should be using `Client.login`, `Client.user` etc.

I recommend reading a [basic tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#:~:text=JavaScript%20is%20a%20programming%20language,styling%3B%20with%20animation%2C%20etc.)

Welcome to programming!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to erase the client id on the terminal. The error is saying that `client is not defined` you must have misspelled the function name. you are using `Client` and on the end write: `client.login('')` which does not exists.